# Why can't access multidementianal arrays like single dimentional

Tags: c, arrays, memory

In C
we have

```
int B[2][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };
```

It is stored in memory as

```
1  2  3  4  5  6

int A[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

It is also stored in memory as

```
1  2  3  4  5  6
```

we can           access A[6] by A[i]  where i=0,2,3..
but we cannot access B[2][3] by B[i ] where i=0,1,2..
I know there are other techniques by which we can access elements of multidimentional arrays 
but we cannot access multidimentional arrays like single dimentional arrays why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has, amongst others, to do with the types of what you access.

`B` is a `int[2][3]`. That means, it has 6× the size of an int and consists of 2 successive `int[3]`.

If you do `[i]`, i being an integer, you get away the first level of indexing. That will give you an expression of type `int[3]`, i. e. an array of 3 `int`s. That is not the same as an int and needs further indexing.

But there is another solution: dereferencing `B` with `[0]` gives you the first array. While this is limited in length, you can use it to access the whole array. So you can achieve your goal with `B[0][5]`.

As said, `B` is a `int[2][3]`, meaning that it is an array of 2 arrays of 3 `int`s. In memory, that looks like

```
offs 0  offs 1  offs 2  offs 3  offs 4  offs 5
B[0][0] B[0][1] B[0][2] B[1][0] B[1][1] B[1][2]
======================= =======================
B[0]                    B[1]
===============================================
B
```

`B[0]` is a 1D-array and as such degrades into a pointer as well. It points to the first element as well, but has a different type. So `B[0]` is of type `int[2]` and cannot be used as an `int` at the same time.

If I consider `B[1]`, it even has a different address. See above how `B[1]` means the 2nd half of all data. `B[0]` and `B[1]` both have 3 times the size of an integer, meaning that the address of `B[1]` is `3*sizeof int` positions away from `B[0]`.

`B[0]` is, as said, the first array shown above. It degrades into a pointer to its first element (to `B[0][0]`) under most circumstances. A pointer, OTOH, can be accessed like an array: `B[0][0]` points to the first element, `B[0][1]` to the 2nd, and so on.

You are allowed to access the whole big array using this pointer, so you can go up to `B[0][5]`. Accessing `B[0][6]` is undefined behaviour in this case, meaning that you access something completely different - or even an area you aren't even allowed to read.

That is how arrays work. Making them work the way you intend to at the same time wouldn't work (how should it?).

If you want to learn more about pointers, have a look at a good C tutorial or book.

Comment: Thanks I was waiting for this answer but i still have a confusion, (why we not intended this way)?..if in both cases the values are stored in a similiar pattern(way) in memory then why not accessible by a same technique?  what is the real internal hardle which does not permits this.What manages all this in memory?

Comment: A big thanks to you now i have a clear picture in my mind,sorry that i cannot vote u up as i have no reputaion points..the thing i understood is that there is nothing like multidimention at low level all the (1d,2d,3d) arrays are stored in contiguous memory locations and they can be considered as array of arrays..

Answer (score 3):

You can interpret them:

```
int B[2][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };

int* b = ( void* )B ;

for( int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++ )
    printf("%d " , b[i] ) ;
```

The same goes for single arrays:

```
int A[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};

int (*a)[3] ;

a = ( void* )A ;

for( int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++ )
    for( int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++ )
        printf("%d " , a[i][j] ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have asked that why this is not allowed to access multi dimention arrays like single dimentional?

Comment: @raz If you didn't gather from the answer it IS "allowed".

Comment: Its "allowed" after conversion to a pointer variable..not directly!

Answer (score 3):

You can access using another pointer to the array as below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int i;
        int a[2][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
        int *b = (int *)a;
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                printf("%d\n", b[i]);
        return 0;
}
```